# Mui list customization

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield, styled-components

I am using the Mui text field to show the select list component. I was trying to customize the list component, but it's not working.

```
const List = styled(TextField)({
'& .MuiList-root': {
background: 'white'
}
})
```

I want to customize the list component using a styled text field. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you able to put this on https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-faraday-ouwwmb?file=/src/CustomTextField.tsx

Comment: @Joseph, I have added the code sandbox link, can you tell me what should I do to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried using SelectProps and it worked

[image]